# Why does lftp interpret parts of URLs as new commands?

Tags: bash, lftp

Why am I getting these errors?

```
Unknown command pass=user.
Unknown command key=site-key.
```

Could it be because I'm using **lftp** or what?

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

##########################################################################
#
# Send queued CiviMail and process back channel for CiviCRM v2.2+
# Make this executable and invoke from cron every (say) 15 minutes
# Not yet tested: no lock on this if previous cron hadn't finished
# but civimail.cronjob.php and CiviMailProcessor.php are multi-entrant
#
##########################################################################
#
# Per-host configuration
#

drupalAuthUser='user'
drupalAuthPass='password'
civicrmSiteKey='site-key'

imapHost='civicrm.example.org'
imapUser='civicrm@example.org'
#imapPass='password'
#
# Prepare URL
#
crmbinurl="http://$imapHost/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin"
crmauthn="?name=$drupalAuthUser&pass=$drupalAuthPass&key=$civicrmSiteKey"
#
echo "Run Drupal cron then check for and send queued CiviMail"
### Heading ##
civimail="${crmbinurl}/civimail.cronjob.php${crmauthn}"
echo $civ
## Heading ##imail
lftp -c "get $civimail > /dev/null"
#
# Wait 10 seconds
#
sleep 2
#
# echo "Process CiviMail backchannel"
#
backchan="${crmbinurl}/CiviMailProcessor.php${crmauthn}"
echo $backchan
## Heading ##
lftp -c "get $backchan > /dev/null"
```

Running `./civicrmcron.sh` gives this output:

```
Run Drupal cron then check for and send queued CiviMail
http://civicrm.example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/civimail.cronjob.php?name=user&pass=password&key=site-key
Unknown command `pass=user'.
Unknown command `key=site-key'.
[22328] Moving to background to complete transfers...
http://civicrm.example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/civimail.cronjob.php?name=user&pass=password&key=site-key
Unknown command `pass=user'.
Unknown command `key=site-key'.
[22332] Moving to background to complete transfers...
```

Comment: Since you are using http, I would recommend wget or curl.

Comment: and what would be the command in wget or curl ?

Comment: `wget --quiet $civimail` or if that is producing output you dont want `wget $civimail > /dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 1):

It's because of your ampersands in your URL for $crmauthn. If you use single quotes it should work:

```
crmauthn='?name='${drupalAuthUser}'&pass='${drupalAuthPass}'&key='${civicrmSiteKey}
```

or:

```
crmauth="'?name='${drupalAuthUser}'&pass='${drupalAuthPass}'&key='${civicrmSiteKey}"
```

Comment: If I do what youre saying it works but than the url gets: http://civicrm.example.org/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin/civimail.cronjob.php?name=user\&pass=password\&key=site-key and this doesnt work

Comment: It seems like it reads that line like im declaring new variable=value inside that string :S

Comment: @ibanezz Sorry, my bad (shouldn't try to answer via the phone)... You should use single quotes so the ampersand doesn't signify a new command. I'll edit my above answer.

Comment: The problem is not that `bash` interprets the `&` as background-command operator - against this the double-quotes help, too. The problem is that lftp interprets them as such. So a single `'...'` around the final URL (where it is given to lftp) would help, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use **links** instead of **lftp**.

```
#!/bin/bash

drupalAuthUser="user"
drupalAuthPass="password"
civicrmSiteKey="site-key"

imapHost="civicrm.example.org"
imapUser="civicrm@example.org"
imapPass="password"

crmbinurl="http://${imapHost}/sites/all/modules/civicrm/bin"
crmauthn="?name=${drupalAuthUser}&pass=${drupalAuthPass}&key=${civicrmSiteKey}"

echo "CiviMail CronJob"
civimail="${crmbinurl}/civimail.cronjob.php${crmauthn}"
echo "  * ${civimail}"
links -source ${civimail} > /dev/null

sleep 2

echo "Process CiviMail backchannel"
backchan="${crmbinurl}/CiviMailProcessor.php${crmauthn}"
echo "  * ${backchan}"
links -source $backchan > /dev/null
```